# PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory arguments problem in Lucene (java)

Tags: java, lucene

I am doing a practice in Java using Lucene. I want to remove "{", "}" and ";" using a CharFilter in a CustomAnalyzer but I don't know how to call the "PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory". I have tried to call it passing it "map" but it doesn't work and it returns an exception. I have also tried with pattern "p" but it's the same.

```
public static ArrayList<String> analyzer_codigo(String texto)throws IOException{
    
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("{", "");
map.put("}", "");
map.put(";", "");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^a-z])");
boolean replaceAll = Boolean.TRUE;
Reader r = new Reader(texto);

    Analyzer ana = CustomAnalyzer.builder(Paths.get("."))
    .addCharFilter(PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory.class,p,"",r)
    .withTokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.class) 
    .addTokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
    .build();

    return muestraTexto(ana, texto);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `Map` to the `PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory` - but the keys you use for the map are those defined in the [JavaDoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_4_0/analysis/common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory.html) for the factory class:

> `pattern="([^a-z])" replacement=""`

This uses Solr documentation to define the keys (`pattern` and `replacement`) together with their Solr default values.

Using these keys, your map becomes:

```java
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("pattern", "\\{|\\}|;");
map.put("replacement", "");
```

The regular expression `\\{|\\}|;` needs to escape the `{` and `}` characters because they have special meanings, and then the regex backslashes also need to be escaped in the Java string.

So, the above regular expression means `{` and `}` and `;` will all be replaced by the empty string.

Your custom analyzer then becomes:

```java
Analyzer analyzer = CustomAnalyzer.builder()
        .withTokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.NAME)
        .addCharFilter(PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory.NAME, map)
        .addTokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.NAME)
        .build();
```

If you use this to index the following input string:

```
foo{bar}baz;bat
```

Then the indexed value will be stored as:

```
foobarbazbat
```

---

Very minor point: I prefer to use `PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory.NAME` instead of `PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory.class` or even just `"patternReplace"` - but these all work.

---

**Update**

Just for completeness:

The `CustomAnalyzer.Builder` supports different ways to add a `CharFilter`. See its [`addCharFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_4_0/analysis/common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/custom/CustomAnalyzer.Builder.html) methods.

As well as the approach shown above, using a `Map`...

```java
.addCharFilter(PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory.NAME, map)
```

...you can also use Java [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html):

```
"key1", "value1", "key2", "value2", ...
```

So, in our case, this would be:

```java
.addCharFilter(PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory.NAME
        "pattern", "\\{|\\}|;", "replacement", "")
```